# Check a string has an integer in the last part using Regex

Tags: regex

I have few lines

Eg:

```
word1-word2-word3-1
word1-word2-word3-23
word1-word2-word3-dr
word1-word2-word3-13-4
word1-word2-word3-drg
word1-word2-word3-word4-4
```

From the above lines i need the following lines by using Regex

```
word1-word2-word3-1
word1-word2-word3-23
word1-word2-word3-word4-4
```

ie. The string ending with a "-{int}"

Comment: Use `/-[0-9]+$/` regex

Comment: Should be a trivial task, why don't you try it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pattern `-\d+$`

The pattern means that we are look for;

1. `-\d+` - hyphen and one or more digits
2. `$` Asserts that we are at the line end.

I don't know what language you are writing this in but assuming you are doing it in Javascript. This pattern can be proved using the code below.

```js
"use strict";
var values = [
  "word1-word2-word3-1",
  "word1-word2-word3-23",
  "word1-word2-word3-dr",
  "word1-word2-word3-13-4",
  "word1-word2-word3-drg",
  "word1-word2-word3-word4-4"
];

values.forEach(value => {
  if (/.*-(?!\d+-)\w+-\d+$/.exec(value)) {
    console.log(value + " has - integer at the end!");
  };
});
```

Comment: It is getting the last line only

Comment: I have included an implementation in `Javascript` to show that the pattern is getting lines that ends with an integer.

Comment: @SamuelToh better it it's `-\d+$`

Comment: I am using php laravel

Comment: i don't need "word1-word2-word3-13-4"

Comment: @user2214646 - are you looking at capturing the last integer value of each matched?

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks. yep `-\d+$` would be better.

Comment: @SamuelToh use this https://regex101.com/r/eC3mK4/1

Comment: @user2214646 - AvinashRaj has given you the answer and has edited my answer. Check the link in his comment.

Comment: Yes! its is working as expected. Thank you very much...  [link](https://regex101.com/r/eC3mK4/1)